# ¿Cómo actualizar paquetes de node en proyecto de angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, firebase

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Firebase, para esto instalé `Angularfire2` con `npm install angularfire2 firebase --save`, pero me salía el siguiente error en la terminal:

```
npm install firebase angularfire2 --save
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11 requires a peer of @angular/common@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ firebase@5.2.0
+ angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.11
updated 2 packages in 15.909s
```

Revisando mi `package.json` me di cuenta que los paquetes tenían otras versiones al mensaje de error:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
  "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
  "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "firebase": "^4.13.1",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
  "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
```

Probé con el comando `npm update`, pero ahora me genera el siguiente error y el proyecto no arranca.

```
ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/auth/auth.d.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firebase.app.module.d.ts(3,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/changes.d.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/collection/collection.d.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/document/document.d.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/firestore.d.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/interfaces.d.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/firestore/observable/fromRef.d.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/storage/observable/fromTask.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/storage/ref.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/storage/storage.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
node_modules/angularfire2/storage/task.d.ts(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase/app'.
```

Esta es la información de mi versión de Angular-cli

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Mi versión de node `v8.10.0` y versión de npm `5.6.0`.

Comment: es solo un peer warning, no debería preocuoparte

Answer (score 0):

No te preocupes por el peer warning, solo es una advertencia, pero no un error.

Trata de tener actualizados todos tus paquetes.